# Building and packaging LLVM clang 3.4 with cmake

Tags: c++11, cmake, clang, llvm

I started studying `cmake` about 2 weeks ago and like it. Thus far, I have been successful in building and packaging (*with the native system packaging format*) `libc++abi`, `libc++`, `llvm` 3.4 all with `cmake` (`libc++abi` with my own `cmake` setup) for RHEL 6.x, Fedora 20+, and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS+.

I would like to create a C++ build environment that

1. **Frees us from dependency on GNU GCC and `libstdc++` completely** (thus we don't want any LLVM RPM/DEB from these aforementioned distros or the [LLVM Debian/Ubuntu nightly packages](http://llvm.org/apt/) download site)
2. **Enables us to explore fully C++11 and C++1y**. In other words, we can try *even* the bleeding edge LLVM/clang anytime we want to while keeping all our build systems clean with package management systems.

Nevertheless, I hit a snag in attempting to build `clang` 3.4 with `cmake`, on a build host running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit, with a *pure* clang 3.3 built by me *without* any dependency on GNU `libstdc++`, together with `libc++` 3.3 and `libc++abi`. The later two have no `libstdc++` dependency either. I built both that way too.

I know of the [Clang - Getting Started](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) Web page really well and have used the instructions there successfully.  But these are *exactly* what I don't want to use. They are incorrect too: the `CMakeLists.txt` of `clang` 3.4 clearly states the following:

```
 1  # If we are not building as a part of LLVM, build Clang as an
 2  # standalone project, using LLVM as an external library:
 3  if( CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR )
 4    project(Clang)
 5    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 6  
 7    set(CLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_SOURCE "" CACHE PATH
 8      "Path to LLVM source code. Not necessary if using an installed LLVM.")
 9    set(CLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_BUILD "" CACHE PATH
10      "Path to the directory where LLVM was built or installed.")
```

See line 1 and 2. But, I have not found any LLVM documentation regarding how to set the `CLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_BUILD`. I tried the following:

```
cmake -DCLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_BUILD="../../llvm-3.4/build" ..
```

and got the following errors:

```
$ clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/build$ cmake -DCLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_BUILD="../../llvm-3.4/build" ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    AddLLVM


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    TableGen


-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_FLAG
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_FLAG - Success
-- Building with -fPIC
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN_FLAG - Success
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.7.8") 
-- Clang version: 3.4
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG - Success
CMake Error at utils/TableGen/CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_tablegen):
  Unknown CMake command "add_tablegen".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

But that's not right!  The LLVM + `compiler-rt` has been installed on the build host with our own `DEB`. And,

```
$ llvm/clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/build$ ls /usr/share/llvm/cmake
AddLLVM.cmake             ChooseMSVCCRT.cmake      linux_issue.cmake  LLVMConfigVersion.cmake   pkg.cmake
AddLLVMDefinitions.cmake  GetSVN.cmake             LLVM-Config.cmake  LLVMParseArguments.cmake  TableGen.cmake
arch.cmake                HandleLLVMOptions.cmake  LLVMConfig.cmake   LLVMProcessSources.cmake
```

So, all required `cmake` modules are there - right on the system!

I would appreciate a hint as to how to coerce `clang` 3.4 to build with `cmake`, with an already installed LLVM 3.4 + `compiler-rt` 3.4.

**Update**:

I decided to do the following:

```
$ llvm/clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/build$ cmake -DCLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_BUILD="/usr" ..
-- Building with -fPIC
-- Clang version: 3.4
-- Found Subversion: /usr/bin/svn (found version "1.6.17") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: ../llvm/clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/build
../llvm/clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/build$ make -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target ClangDriverOptions
Scanning dependencies of target clang-tblgen
[  0%] Building Options.inc...
[  0%] ../llvm/clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/include/clang/Driver/Options.td:15:9: error: Could not find include file 'llvm/Option/OptParser.td'
include "llvm/Option/OptParser.td"
        ^
.../llvm/clang3.4/_tars/clang-3.4/include/clang/Driver/Options.td:15:9: Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangASTNodesEmitter.cpp.o
error: Unexpected input at top level
include "llvm/Option/OptParser.td"
        ^
make[2]: *** [include/clang/Driver/Options.inc.tmp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [include/clang/Driver/CMakeFiles/ClangDriverOptions.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  0%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangAttrEmitter.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangCommentCommandInfoEmitter.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangCommentHTMLNamedCharacterReferenceEmitter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangCommentHTMLTagsEmitter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangDiagnosticsEmitter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangSACheckersEmitter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/NeonEmitter.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/TableGen.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../llvm/clang3.4/_tars/llvm-3.4/build/bin/clang-tblgen
[  1%] Built target clang-tblgen
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

That's better. Looks like `clang` 3.4's default `CMakeLists.txt` is not even QA-ed x-( Yikes x-(

Comment: I am still new to `cmake`, but I suspect that the `CMakeLists.txt` that comes with `clang` 3.4 is incorrect.  The top statement that I quoted is *misleading*.  If the LLVM has been installed, with custom modules in the `/usr/share/llvm/cmake`, then the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` can't depend on `CLANG_PATH_TO_LLVM_SOURCE` alone IMHO.  So, I wonder this statement from LLVM clang folks is really feasible?, quoted "If we are not building as a part of LLVM, build Clang as an standalone project, using LLVM as an external library"

Comment: +1 for your efforts to build everything yourself. But you do know there is a semi-official apt repo at http://llvm.org/apt/ ?

Comment: @TemplateRex.  I prefer not to use these. They all have GNU libstdc++ dependency, which doesn't fit our GNU free C++ build environment requirement.

Comment: @user183394 You do know the Linux kernel is... GPL? And Glibc is... GNU? And GCC isn't a bad thing. At all. Especially on Linux. Clang isn't perfect, and LLVM isn't always as good as GCC at optimizing. Anyways, I guess what I'm saying is that you're making it difficult for yourself for no obvious reason.

Comment: @rubenvb. I have nothing against things GNU, but we have our needs, which I prefer not to elaborate on SO (too OT). To give you a flavor: how can you build C++11 apps on RHEL 5.8? :> Regarding your comments about clang's performance, I can only suggest http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=llvm34_gcc49_compilers&num=1 whenever you have time. Regarding making my life difficult: we need to use system native package formats. `cmake` and `cpack` is really good at meeting this requirement. Within 2 weeks, I can already slice and dice highly elaborate `cmake` listfiles, IMHO !bad :)

Comment: @user183394 Build C++11 apps on RHEL 5.8: build custom GCC 4.8.2, and link statically to libstdc++ and libgcc. Simple as that. It's good to see LLVM further improving on optimization. Soon they should also have (or already have) OpenMP support. DOn't get me wrong, I'm a fan :-p

Comment: @rubenvb You could do that route too. But to get the modern GCC into older Linux, it takes just the same (or more, note your keyword "custom" :)  effort for what we wish to do.  Besides, I like `lldb` from the LLVM project too. I also favor to update a system in an *orthogonal* manner :) Don't get me wrong either. I have been using GCC since 0,9 in 1992 :) Take care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to *tough it out* as any self-respecting engineer would do :) I simply vi-ed the following two files and add full path to the offending include, and then that's that.

1. `Options.td`
2. `CC1AsOptions.td`

Now I can build all desired LLVM main projects without `libstdc++` dependency, all linked with `libc++` and `libc++abi`. Hooray :)

So, I have confirmed that

- Some instructions given in [Getting Started: Building and Running Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) are misleading, e.g. **7**.
- All main LLVM projects (except `compiler-rt` AFAIK) can be built with `cmake`.  There is no need to lump them together under the LLVM source tree for building.   You definitely can build nearly all of them separately on Linux, unlike what these "official" documentation may lead you to believe :>

The LLVM team should really think through and minimize the apparent cyclic dependency among all projects.  Bootstrapping LLVM/clang on various Linux distros (especially older ones such as RHEL 5.x) *without* GNU `libstdc++` dependency is too tedious - speaking from my first hand experience.  They can be done (I have done it :) but it's not for the faint of heart.

Comment: do you have a website / GitHub page where you document the full build process? that would be really valuable!

Comment: Not yet.  Once I get this whole system polished up.  Right now, it's IMHO still too q&d :(

Comment: @user183394 what about now? Can you release *anything* to those of us suffering?

Comment: @user183394 I'd like to check it too, it would be really helpful for me at this moment. I'm interested in packaging it from an svn checkout: http://nosubstance.me/articles/2015-01-29-better-completion-for-cpp/.

Answer (score 2):

I think this project does what you're trying to do:

https://github.com/rsmmr/install-clang

I've used it on FC16+, but did run into bootstrapping issues on RHEL5.x.

Comment: I am afraid that it wouldn't. As a prelude of my current effort, I have already tried to build a similar one. As you pointed out above, the system wouldn't work in old Linux. The most challenging part: *to build a `libstdc++` free C++1y build environment on "(old) Linux", you must have a build environment that's C++11 ready*!!  It took me a while to break this cyclic-dependency, first in last year with 3.3, and this year with 3.4.  In addition, I need not only a build system, but also a *packaging* system that uses the system's native packaging format. `cmake` + `cpack` support this need well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and find that just copy `llvm/include/llvm` to this `Driver` dir and it will work.